# I can't understand codility PermMissingElem wrong using C/C++

Tags: c++, int, max, permutation, long-integer

I used C++ for solving problem, codility PermMissingElem.
I didn't use `xor`, just sum of sequence.

c++

```
 int solution(vector<int> &A) {
        // write your code in C++11 (g++ 4.8.2)
        int n = A.size();
        long long sum = ((n+1)*(n+2))/2;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            sum -= A[i];
        }
        return (int)sum;
    }
```

It result in 80% of test score for fail to large test = ~100000 
Wrong answer example,

> got -2147483647 expected 1

However, if using java following, it results in 100%.

java

```
 public int solution(int[] A) {

            long N = A.length + 1;
            long total = N * (N + 1) / 2;

            for (int i : A) {

                total -= i;
            }

            return (int)total;
        }
```

What's difference between c++ and java?
I used data type of sum, long, long long, long long int ..

Thx.

Comment: Why are you returning a long long as an int? What if it's larger than the possible value of the int?

Comment: Perhaps compiling it 64bit might help

Comment: Is `sum = ((n+1)*(n+2))/2` supposed to be equivalent to `total = N * (N + 1) / 2`?

Comment: Also, you can use `for (const auto& e : A)` as a loop instead

Comment: @Link because size of n could be 100,000, so i think long long can cover the value n*n. I think codility error message means overflow.. but i can't totally understand that

Comment: @fisache It can also be `>sizeof(int)` and then you have problems.

Answer (score 1):

You store n in an int. So when you square it, you still have an int. Then you assign that int to a long long sum, but it's too late because overflow has already occurred.

Comment: Thanks! Oh.. I had not thought about that.. I solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is 100% javascript solution:

```
function solution(A) {
    if (!A.length) return 1;
    let n = A.length + 1;
    return (n + (n * n - n) / 2) - A.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
}
```

We return 1 if the given array is empty, which is the missing element in an empty array.

Next we calculate the 'ordinary' series sum, assuming the first element in the series is always 1. Then we find the difference between the given array and the full series, and return it. This is the missing element.

The mathematical function I used here are series sum, and last element:

- S<sub>n</sub> = (n/2)*(a<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>n</sub>)
- a<sub>n</sub> = a<sub>1</sub> + (n - 1)*d